# How to send data from create view to controller using viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im new with MVC and I have a create view using entityframework.

I also created a viewmodel having 3 models inside

Sample Code

```
namespace Sample.ViewModels
{
    public class AItems{
        
            public List<AType> ATypes { get; set; }
            public List<VType> VTypes { get; set; }
            public List<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

The AType is actually a dropdown selection for the MyItems ActionType
The VType is for my dropdown selection for MyItems VisualType
and the MyItem is the actual item with more information.

MyItem.AType is actually an ID of the AType table and MyItem.VType is an ID of VType
but i want to show in the create view the equivalent name of that type so i added them to the ViewModel.

I use this viewmodel in my create view.

Sample View

```
    @model Sample.ViewModels.AItems 
    
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "New Item";
    }
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Articles</h4>
        <hr />
    
        <div class="form-group">
            
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="vtypeid">View</label>
                <select idd="vtypeid"class="form-select" aria-label="">
                    @foreach (var vtype in Model.VTypes)
                    {
                        <option value="@vtype.ID">@vtype._name</option>
                    }
                    
                </select>            
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(p => p.MyItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(p => p.MyItems, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

As you can see, in the sample vtype, i loaded each vtype name in a dropdown.
Still I want to pass the model MyItems to the Create Controller of MyItem which accepts the MyItem Model.

Heres the Create Action of MyItemController

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,v_type_id,a_type_id,name,description")] MyItems myitems)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.MyItems.Add(myitems);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(myitems);
        }
```

How can I pass the model MyItem in the controller create action?
Also, I cannot use the model MyItem.name property in the @Html.EditFor.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, always i try use Bind to get some data from the View i have problems in release, if is a possibility for you i sugest, pass the data using a call ajax, if you want i post a litlle example

Comment: hi. yes pls. if u can provide an example would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

so i create a little example how pass data use ajax call,

in your view you have:

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="" id="id_dropdown">
        @foreach (var vtype in Model.VTypes)
        {
            <option value="@vtype.ID">@vtype._name</option>
        }                   
    </select> 
    
    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.MyItems, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = 
    "form-control", id="id_input" } })
        
    <button id="id_button">Send Data</button>
    </div> 

    <script>    
        $(document).on("click", ".id_button", function () {
            var data = new Object();
            data.id_dropdown = $(".id_dropdown").val();
            data.id_input = $(".id_input").val();              
            if (data != null) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/View",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                        } else {                            
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

in controller(pass Data to items and Save(Added)):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddPost(MyItems Data)
    {
        MyItems items = new MyItems ()
        {
            id_dropdown = Data.id_dropdown,
            id_input = Data.id_input,

        };
        db.Entry(items).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

if you dont understand anything tell me